# What's the term used for the abbreviated language found in headlines etc?

Tags: single-word-requests, headline-english

Is there a particular term for the abbreviated language used in headlines (the removal of at least articles and conjunctions)?

Comment: [Related](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37659/is-sent-from-my-iphone-correctly-punctuated-and-capitalized/37662#37662)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a name for the abbreviated syntax used in signs?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/251264/is-there-a-name-for-the-abbreviated-syntax-used-in-signs) TL;DR: Headlinese or Telegraphic Speech

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mårdh (1980) refers to this type of language as "headlinese". (Mårdh, Ingrid. 1980. *Headlinese: On the grammar of English front page headlines*. Malmö: CWK Gleerup.) See also [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese).

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. I suppose I should have known to check Wikipedia first!

Answer (score -1):

A particularly bewildering headline can be referred to as a [crash blossom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_ambiguity#In_headlines). This term was taken from the headline: "Violinist linked to JAL crash blossoms".