# Is there a name for the abbreviated syntax used in signs etc?

Tags: grammar, abbreviations

For instance, a train sign might say `South bound trains this platform` rather than `Use this platform to take a Southbound train.`

There is an interesting lack of articles and sometimes verbs, is there a name for this style (or a reason for it)?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telegram_style)--

Telegram style, telegraph style, telegraphic style or telegraphese describes a clipped way of writing that attempts to abbreviate words and pack as much information into the smallest possible number of words and/or characters.

It originated in the telegraph age when telecommunication consisted only of short messages transmitted by hand over the telegraph wire. The telegraph companies charged for their service by the number of words in a message, with a maximum of 15 characters per word for a plain-language telegram, and 10 per word for one written in code. The style developed to minimize costs but still convey the message clearly and unambiguously.

Of the four names mentioned, **telegraphic style** is the version that I'm familiar with.

Comment: Aha!  Thank you.  The [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telegram_style) was a very interesting read too.

Comment: As terse as they are, telegraphs are far more verbose than signs.  Signs have little need to establish context.

Comment: @TimRomano The description in the wikipedia article is appropriate for both. It's just that "the smallest possible number of words" for a sign is smaller than for a typical telegram, because of what you say.

Answer (score 3):

It is also the style of headlines in newspapers, where the topic is reduced to the shortest possible form.

Comment: Headlines are rather more verbose than signs.

Comment: @TimRomano that depends heavily on the publication (as well as the style of sign)

Comment: The neologism is 'headlinese'.

Answer (score 1):

In software development this concept is called terseness or Verbose vs Terse. https://wikidiff.com/verbose/terse

Comment: Maybe, I dunno. But the general meanings of terse and verbose do not mean removing little words like of and the. It means being succinct. Whereas telegraphy style means  you remove words.