# Safety First or Safety's first?

Tags: expressions

Is Expression "Safety First" grammatically correct, or " Safety's first"?
Also,There is a website called TED "ideas worth spreading".. I think it should be ideas are worth spreading because worth isn't a verb?

Comment: You should ask one question at a time. "Safety first" is the standard expression.

Comment: "Ideas worth spreading" is an abbreviation of "ideas that are worth spreading". For more information, see [this answer on Whiz-deletion](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50962/what-is-a-noun-modifying-clause/50971#50971)

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of **telegraphic styl**e.  See my answer below for more on what that means:

[No article? Why?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/268492/no-article-why/268498#268498)

Run a search on "telegraphic style" in the search box above for other similar answers.

Answer (score -1):

i think regarding the question on safety, the answer is safety first  not safety's first because its not countable so no plural......the plural can be put on the rule regarding  this topic e.g rule's first..i hope that is of help.

anna

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. The term *safety's* is not plural - it is a contraction of *safety is*. So *safety's first* expands to *safety is first*.