# Why there are no article in the "Alert at time of event"

Tags: articles

Here is the screenshot from the Apple Calendar event quick preview:
[image]

Why it is not a

> Alert at THE time of event

or

> Alert at time of THE event

or even

> Alert at THE time of THE event

I suppose there are definitely no place for "A" article in reason the subject of the question is specific and known - we know what is the time and the event.
But why there are no definite article?
And is it correct to say "Alert at time of event" in conversation?

Comment: Simply for brevity, in the same way that newspaper headlines omit articles. And, no, you would not say it in conversation (unless quoting directly from the screen).

Comment: @KateBunting if you do not create the answer, i can't to mark it as solution

Comment: See *[Is there a name for the abbreviated syntax used in signs?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/251264/is-there-a-name-for-the-abbreviated-syntax-used-in-signs)* This is an example of telegraphic or telegram style, examples of which are used in newspaper headlines, diaries and journals, warnings and alerts, instructions and recipes, street signs, SMS messages, and so forth.

Comment: @choster I argue against of duplication of this issue. It may relate some how, bu my question was about using this style in conversation too which is missing in the post you are reference.

Comment: It's still a duplicate then. This question would be available but closed for new answers. The other question would cover the topic, which I agree overlaps in all critical ways, and answers the question. Readers would see both, so they'd know the answers there apply here.

Comment: ... The further question ("Is [headlinese] correct in conversation?") is unsuitable on a site aimed at linguists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The articles are omitted for brevity, in the same way as they are in newspaper headlines; and, no, you would not say it in conversation (unless quoting directly from the screen).

Comment: In spite of what some mods might say, I think the comment response was appropriate.