# "Fidel Castro Dead" - Is this Slang or common English Usage?

Tags: headline-english

English is not my mother tongue, so I'm not sure if the title of an article I've read is legit: "Fidel Castro Dead". Shouldn't it be "Fidel Castro is dead"?

Comment: Newspaper titles tend to be short and use only the words that are essential.

Comment: I just edited your question among other things capitalizing *usage* and *slang*. Headlines use other rules for capitalizing and sentence structure than regular sentences. You can also see that *dead* is capitalized in your example which as you not correctly would not be the case in a regular sentence.

Comment: I'm curious, do newspapers in your language give full sentences for headlines? But yes, in normal speaking 'is' is required, but in newspaper headlines it is assumed. No one in their right mind would speak like a newspaper headline.

Comment: See many questions and answers here starting with http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104968/headline-language

Answer (score 6):

It's ***[Headlinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese)***, not ordinary English:

> - an abbreviated writing style used in newspaper headlines. Because space is limited, headlines are written in a compressed telegraphic style, using special syntactic conventions.

Wikipedia