# Available or is available

Tags: grammar, differences

I'm a little bit confused which version is correct:

1. New version available
2. New version is available

Comment: 1. Is not a full sentence so is suitable as a headline. 2. Is a complete sentence but needs an article: "A new version is available"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Headline Language.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104968/headline-language) Also [Why do newspaper headlines use strange syntax rules?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7257/why-do-newspaper-headlines-use-strange-syntax-rules)