# About cases you don't use the article "the" and "a" | Would anybody be able to tell me why there is no article in this case?

Tags: articles, writing, subjects, titles

I read an article of the link below:

https://www.cbc.ca/news/world/hong-kong-protester-shot-1.5303783

My question is why the subject "Hong Kong protester" in the title has no article "a" and similarly the specific word "China's Communist Party" has no article "the" in front of them, even though those articles are put in front of each word in the body.

Would anybody be able to tell me why in this case?

Comment: It's called "headlinese"...See [this EL&U post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104968/headline-language/104970#104970)

Comment: @Cascabel that is what I've been looking for! That makes sense. Thanks:)