# Do we need to use the article "the" while talking about numbers and ratio?

Tags: grammar, articles, definite-articles

I would like to know if both sentences below require the article "the" at the beginning of the sentence.

#### Sentence 1:

- Total number of cases in the US has increased by 2.2%.
- The total number of cases in the US has increased by 2.2%.

#### Sentence 2:

- Ratio of deaths to the number of cases in the US is 19 to 1.
- The ratio of deaths to the number of cases in the US is 19 to 1.

What rules of grammar do I need to consider while deciding if we need to use "the" or not with these sentences?

Clarification: These sentences are not used in headlines but in bullet points to communicate highlights of a day.

Comment: You want to use the definite article in these sentences.

Comment: It doesn't make a big difference as long as the sentences read better.  Sentence 1; both are correct.  As for sentence 2, the second sentence is less wordy conveying the same message.

Comment: 'Is this a standard sentence in script or conversation, or is it rolling text accompanying pictures on a news program?' You'd lose marks in a piece of writing for dropping the articles.

Comment: The version with the definite article is always correct and recommended in a piece of writing. In titles or list, however, the articles are sometimes omitted.

Comment: @RamPillai I have updated the second question. I intended both options to be equally wordy with the sole exception of the presence or absence of the definite article.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth These are short sentences being presented in email notifications. The email notifications are supposed to present the highlights of the day.

Comment: In this case the article can be omitted.

Comment: The x of y usually requires the **the**. The number of cases is high. Case numbers are high.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Headline Language](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104968/headline-language) You will find other relevant threads in links there. Essentially, 'Do you need to use articles in ...' usually depends on the register you're in. Emails, headlinese usually used. Jane Austen ...?

Comment: @JulesCocovin My sentences are being used in a list as bullet points. Considering this, are both of these okay: "Total number of cases in the US has increased by 2.2%.", "Ratio of deaths to the number of cases in the US is 19 to 1."

Comment: @LoneLearner I think bullet points do not require simplification. PS. I can't remember the name of the British grammarian, but I remember his piece of advice - if you omit "the", omit it throughout the sentence. PPS. US deaths/cases ratio is 1/19. Hmm? (BTW Note that it should be 1/19 not 19/1, I guess)